# should i remove this not upgraded packages?

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried uninstalling android studio and i am getting this and also many times before i have got this type of lines, but in my file system i have .android and .AndroidStudio folders and many more. How to remove android studio completely from my Ububtu system.

```
(base) TravelMate-P243:~$ sudo apt-get remove android-studio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'android-studio' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 58 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Run `sudo purge android-studio`.

Comment: it says purge: command not found

Comment: The above comment is right. Purge is the way to go to get rid of an application completely but there is likely to always be files or folders left behind. Things like custom configuration files and logs that weren't generated or installed by apt so apt won't remove them and it'd be a case of removing them manually as and when you find them.

Comment: Sry `sudo apt purge android-studio`

Comment: sorry its also not working

Comment: If you run `sudo apt dist-upgrade` it should show you what those 58 not upgraded packages are.

Comment: Also, did you install the android-studio as a snap app?  If so, `sudo snap remove android-studio` should remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt remove android-studio` will **remove the package** with all of its included binaries and libraries from your system. It will also remove (or at least mark as unused and ready for removal) any packages that were installed as **dependency** of this one and which are not needed by anything else any more.

It may leave some system-wide configuration files behind though, which would help you to restore pretty much the same application state again when you reinstall the package later.

With `sudo apt purge android-studio` instead, the package manager will also **purge all related system configuration** files.

However, **`apt` will never remove user data**. If the application created any folders and files to store user configuration or anything else **in your home directory**, you have to **delete those manually** if you want. The package manager is not supposed to touch user homes.

For more information, check [Why don't programs completely uninstall (remove all their files) when I remove them?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1120246/367990)