# How to remove data files from uninstalled applications?

Tags: uninstall, disk, cleanup

I am searching for a maintenance tool that cleans up left overs, including in /home, from uninstalled applications based on the history of my uninstalls.

These leftover files can be small and therefore stay under the radar of disk useage tools, but they can also be huge (a recent baloo index on .local/share was 27 GB).

This topic has been discussed over the years, but without resolve for me. In addition to my request I want the tool to find leftovers from previous OS installations that have wiped the install history.

PS:

- I appreciate that no package uninstall should remove user data, (see [Why don't programs completely uninstall (remove all their files) when I remove them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120246/why-dont-programs-completely-uninstall-remove-all-their-files-when-i-remove-t/1120251#1120251)).
- This excellent post [What is the correct way to completely remove an application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application/187891#187891) covers how to remove ex-configs.
- I am aware of [bleachbit](https://www.bleachbit.org/). But it is brute force and has brought my computer to a halt by creating GBs of tmp data while cleaning.

Comment: An apt removal should include all data (exceptions: /home, /etc). An apt purge should also include all data (exception: /home). Any other result is a bug in the application or the removal script. If this behavior can be duplicated reliably, then please file a bug report. Additional applications to work around a bug are not recommended.

Comment: I doubt there is a tool that can guarantee the removal of all data for any application, so good luck with that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Advanced disk usage analyzing software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98382/advanced-disk-usage-analyzing-software)

Comment: Tks Norbert, but small files are difficult to detect with the tool you have suggested,

Comment: Have you tried [Stacer](https://www.fossmint.com/stacer-ubuntu-system-optimizer/)?

Comment: Stacer does not find the leftover .local/share/baloo files.